# how to get the area under the curve or integral in r

Tags: r, derivative, integral, longitudinal

I have a curve as the data below and I would like to calculate the area under the curve (integral) of this curve made by x and y points. Is it correct to do in the way below? and how can I calculate the area under the curve within a specific interval without knowing the function of curve?
I am going to repeat this with the rest of my data for each individual with repeated measurements. Also, I need to calculate the area under the curve for the first and second derivative values. should I do the same?
Thank you for your advice.

```
structure(list(x = c("76.37", "76.89", "77.36", "77.86", "78.86", 
                 "79.37", "79.87", "80.36", "80.5", "81.2"), 
           y = c("2.1", "2.29", "2.47", "2.65", "2.82", "2.99", "3.16", "3.31", "3.46", "3.5")), 
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-10L))


library(pracma)
AUC = trapz(data$x,data$y)
```

Comment: How can you calculate derivatives when you don't have any function ?

Comment: @Necklondon  I have the first and second derivative values of y.

Comment: @onyambu I have diffrernt curves, where each might have linear or nonlinear function. can I use: prod(sapply(df, \(x)diff(range(x))))/2 + diff(range(df$x)) * min(df$y) ? But then dividing by two should change when the distance between x points is not 2? and also lower and upper bound of interval is the min and max you defined? thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could approximate the function thus use `approxfun` with a linear interpolation

```
integrate(approxfun(df$x, df$y), min(df$x), max(df$x))
13.78885 with absolute error < 0.00049
```

Note that a rough approximation of the area yields a number closer to this. This assumes the region is trapezoidal.

```
prod(sapply(df, \(x)diff(range(x))))/2 + diff(range(df$x)) * min(df$y)
[1] 13.524
```

Comment: thank you. Is it correct to use "approxfun" with a linear interpolation for the curves that are not linear? also, how can I can I do the same integral within an interval, lets say within an interval of x?

Comment: @Nima plot your fucntion and you will notice that it seems linear. Otherwise you can always fit any kind of function using `nls` or even `lm` then you can integrate that. Yes you can integrate from lower to upper. Just change the values of lower to what you want and upper to what you want

Comment: thanks. do you mean in the case the curve in not linear I can do below code to get the function? integrate(nls(df$x, df$y), min(df$x), max(df$x))? And another question, which one is better to use for intergral as you wrote above: integrate () or prod()?

Comment: @Nima not really, you will estimete the curve using nls, get the equation parameters, then use `predict` funtion to write your own function which can be used in the integrate function. Note that the prod funtion is not integration. I  just used to show that if indeed the data was linear(as in your case) then the area of the trapezoid will be 13.5, but it is not purely linear. So its just a very ROUGH estimate

Comment: @Nima I know nothing about trapz(). Also note that the curve can be anything that does not even resemble known figures.

Comment: @anyambu the trapz () estimate the area of the trapezoid.

Comment: @Nima But the estimated curve can be rough. Not trapezoid at all. So I do not think using trapz is correct. Use integration

Comment: but why when I use: nls(df$x, df$y) I get error of Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Comment: @Nima that is not how `nls` is used. type `help('nls')` to see how it is used